# Error in installing oracle forms 11.1.2.2.0 in ubuntu 13

Tags: linux, forms, ubuntu, oracle11g

Everyone i'm trying to install oracle forms 11.1.2.2.0  into ubuntu (installing in a virtual machine).but i have an error when i run it during the installation in the  **prerequisite check** stape.I have 2 warning in checking recommended operating system packages and checking kernel parameters
i already installed weblogic 10.3.6.0

Firstly i  a Create directory for Middleware home

$ cd /u01/app
$ mkdir Middleware

then i set JAVA_HOME/PATH by adding the 2 lines in the .bash_profile file
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/java

and activate the new path settings immediately:
$ source ~/.bash_profile

after that i run the weblogic via the command:
java -jar wls1036_generic.jar

the weblogic was installed successfully.

in the end i run the forms by going to the Disk1 directory and

Start the installer:

./runInstaller

but in the step :prerequisite check i had these 2 warnings(status)

checking recommended operating system packages

and checking kernel parameters
thank you for help

Comment: Describe error, show us commands, don't make it harder than it is.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your response,i modified the body of the issue;thank you for your help

Comment: Hi i run it with the command ./runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs
but i have this errors in the step installations location :
Unable to detect machine platform or JVM bits
Specified Weblogic home location is not a valid location
Specified Middleware home location either not valid or mssing

any issue please

Comment: I never worked with oracle forms, I replayed here so you can make your question better and someone else could answer you ;)